# How to produce a 503 service unavailable on Google cloud run?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am working on a disaster recovery strategy and would like to automate the cloud run infrastructure deployment on the Google Cloud platform if the service is unavailable for more than 10 minutes.

To do the above automation, I want to check if my cloud run's [get public API's](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) are responding or not and send an alert that will trigger the automation and provision the resource

**Problem** 
I am not able to produce a `503 error` on the demo container (hello-world) of cloud run, I tried sending `10000 requests` using python multiprocessing with `1 concurrency` on Cloud run keeping **max instances at 1** and **minimum instances at 0**, `Memory- 128MB, CPU-1`

How can I produce a 503 error on the cloud run demo container hello-world and see the what is the status of the `get public API`?

**What I don't want to do**
I don't want to add a healthcheck to the container application and use that healthcheck to determine the availability of the container cloud run service.

Comment: Create an endpoint such as /test/503 in your application and return HTTP error 503.

Comment: John Hanley- it would then be the application returning 503 error but the api https://run.googleapis.con/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespace/project/servicename would still return a ready status or true status i suppose

Answer (score 1):

**Update** I misread your question and assumed you were looking to use Cloud Storage.

Here's two options:

- [Mocks](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/mocks.md)
- There's an `api_option` in [ClientOptions](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/client_options.html#google.api_core.client_options.ClientOptions).

##### Mocking

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import HttpMockSequence
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions

http = HttpMockSequence([
    ({"status":"503"},"")
])

service = build("run","v1",http=http)

namespace = "foo"
service = "bar"

name = "namespaces/{namespace}/services/{service}".format(
  namespace=namespace,
  service=service,
)

rqst = service.namespaces().services().get(name=name)
resp = rqst.execute(http=http)

print(resp)

service.close()
```

And then running it:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/foo/services/bar?alt=json returned "Ok">
```

##### `ClientOptions`

You can point the client to your own "implementation" of the API using `ClientOptions` that always returns 503s:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions

client_options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint="http://{host}:{port}".format(
  host="localhost",
  port="8080",
)

service = build("run","v1",client_options=client_options)

namespace = "foo"
service = "bar"

name = "namespaces/{namespace}/services/{service}".format(
  namespace=namespace,
  service=service,
)

rqst = service.namespaces().services().get(name=name)
resp = rqst.execute(http=http)

print(resp)

service.close()
```

And then running it:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting http://localhost:8080/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/foo/services/bar?alt=json returned "Ok">
```

> **NOTE** This time, I've an HTTP server with a `/` handler that always returns `503` (ServiceUnavailable). The error comes from `localhost:8080`

**Original**

```py
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import storage

client_options = ClientOptions(
    api_endpoint="[[ENDPOINT]]"
)

client = storage.Client(client_options=client_options)
```

> **NOTE** You may want to migrate from [`gcloud`](https://pypi.org/project/gcloud/) to [`google.cloud`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/)

Comment: @John Mich can you please let us know if this answer helped you ?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty, I'll try it soon, have not tried it as of now. To put it more simply, I want to break my cloud run service and want to analyze a response coming from run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespace/<project>/<servicename>. I will check how this will respond in the current scenario and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: try uploading a large file. On an instance with limited amount of memory that presumably will naturally result in 503.

```
from gcloud import storage
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import os


credentials_dict = {
    'type': 'service_account',
    'client_id': os.environ['BACKUP_CLIENT_ID'],
    'client_email': os.environ['BACKUP_CLIENT_EMAIL'],
    'private_key_id': os.environ['BACKUP_PRIVATE_KEY_ID'],
    'private_key': os.environ['BACKUP_PRIVATE_KEY'],
}
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    credentials_dict
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project='myproject')
bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('myfile')
blob.upload_from_filename('myfile')
```

Comment: But this would break the boot disk instead of the instance, right?

Comment: @johnmich I'd assume there is a boot disk protection from such type of "attacks" and it should be fine. Otherwise I think tinkering proxy/connection settings might be a viable option.

Comment: I tried this, doesn't work. The instance still has the "running" status and the disk has the "ready" status